# Error during OpenStack installation: ./stack.sh:exit_trap:539 echo 'Error on exit'

Tags: openstack, virtualization, devstack

I am new to OpenStack. While installing devstack on my VM, during the execution of

> ./stack.sh

using ubuntu 16.04, I am getting the following error:

```
+lib/etcd3:install_etcd3:121               echo ' /opt/stack/devstack/files/etcd-v3.1.7-linux-arm64.tar.gz'
+lib/etcd3:install_etcd3:123               sha256sum -c /opt/stack/devstack/files/etcd.sha256sum
sha256sum: /opt/stack/devstack/files/etcd.sha256sum: no properly formatted SHA256 checksum lines found
+lib/etcd3:install_etcd3:1                 exit_trap
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:521                  local r=1
++./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                  jobs -p
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:522                  jobs=
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:525                  [[ -n '' ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:531                  '[' -f '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:536                  kill_spinner
+./stack.sh:kill_spinner:417               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:538                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:539                  echo 'Error on exit'
Error on exit
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:540                  generate-subunit 1517844452 85 fail
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:541                  [[ -z /opt/stack/logs ]]
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:544                  /opt/stack/devstack/tools/worlddump.py -d /opt/stack/logs
World dumping... see /opt/stack/logs/worlddump-2018-02-05-152857.txt for details
+./stack.sh:exit_trap:550                  exit 1
```

I also check the worlddump file, but I didn't see nothing strange, for me.

I strictly follow the steps described in this guide: https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/

Could the hardware on which I am working cause this error?
Any tips?
Thanks

Comment: hi i'm having the same problem, did you end up solving this ?